# Finding repeated numbers in a 2x2 array. (Java)

Tags: java

I am a student who is somewhat new to programming, I have been asked to create a program in java that reads the numbers in a sudoku grid and make sure that there are no repeated numbers in columns and rows, this is what I have so far:

```
  int e=0;
  int h=0;
  boolean k = true;
  int sd = 0;

  for (int i=0; i< 9; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j< 9; j++){
      if (sudoku[j][0]==sudoku[i][0]){
        k=false;
    }
}
  }
  for (int i=0; i< 9; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j< 9; j++){
      if (sudoku[0][j]==sudoku[0][i]){
        k = false;
    }
}
}

      if ( k){
        System.out.println("Valid sudoku");
      }
      else if ( !k){
        System.out.println("Not a valid sudoku");
      }

}
```

My code does not work the way it should since it always shows valid sudoku, even when it is not supposed to, I would like to know how could I fix this.
Before hand I thank you for any help you could give me. (I got the idea to scan as if it was a 1x1 sudoku but adding 0 so it starts at the 0th column and row in each case).

Comment: At a time like this, you would be robbing yourself of a critical learning opportunity to have somebody else point out the problem to you. Instead, please learn how to use your IDE's debugger and step through the code line by line (hint: it won't take very long until you hit the wrong piece).

Comment: And if you don't use an IDE, add print statements to understand the flow of your code.

Comment: either you can try with three loops or simply you can use HashSet and check if numbers are repeating.

Comment: Here's a hint. Think about what the 0s mean in `if (sudoku[j][0]==sudoku[i][0])`

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I have , and I found out that it does never come true , assuming 0 as the first character of the array , If i set it to 1 it does work ,However ,  I am not sure as to why that happens, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Before you read this code, I'll just advice you that there would be more elegant solutions to your problem. I've written this code in reference to your code.

In this code, `testColumn()` and `testRow()` are two methods whoose work is just to check whether a number(passed as an argument to these functions) exists in this row/column or not.

```
int testColumn(int grid[9][9], int column, int number) {
    for(int row=0; row<9; row++) {
        if(grid[row][column]==number) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int testRow(int grid[9][9], int row, int number) {
    for(int column=0; column<9; column++) {
        if(grid[row][column]==number) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void checkRowColumn(int grid[9][9]) {
    boolean k=true;

    for(int row=0; row<9; row++) {
        for(int column=0; column<9; column++) {

            int numberToCheck = grid[row][column];

            if(testColumn(grid, column, numberToCheck)) {
                k = false;
            }
            if(testRow(grid, row, numberToCheck)) {
                k = false;
            }

        }
    }

    if(k) {
        System.out.println("Valid Sudoku");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Sudoku");
    }
}
```

*P.S. I haven't compiled this code. I apologize in advance if there's any compile time errors. I welcome any suggestions or edits advised.*

Comment: I see, thank you so much for taking the time for writting it , I am aware that probably there are more elegant ways to do it , However since I am still learning I was not sure as to how to do them, I really appreciate you helping me in this way. I will mess around with it for a while to see some of the differences.